# Stripe - Discrepancy between logs and retrieved data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I got 2 issues with Stripe.

1. Is this error solvable only by contacting the customer support?

   `You cannot change 'legal_entity[personal_id_number]' via API if an account is verified. Please contact support@stripe.com if you need to change the legal entity information associated with this account.`
2. The log on the dashboard and the retrieved data are different. The latest log on the dashboard is as below but I did communicate with Stripe after this, and the dashboard didn't get this.

   ```
   {
     "id": "acct_*************",
     "object": "account",
     "business_logo": null,
     "business_name": null,
     "business_url": null,
     "charges_enabled": true,
     "country": "US",
     "debit_negative_balances": false,
     "decline_charge_on": {
       "avs_failure": false,
       "cvc_failure": false
     },
     "default_currency": "usd",
     "details_submitted": false,
     "display_name": null,
     "email": "xxxxxxx@mailinator.com",
     "external_accounts": {
       "object": "list",
       "data": [
       ],
       "has_more": false,
       "total_count": 0,
       "url": "/v1/accounts/acct_*************/external_accounts"
     },
     "keys": {
       "secret": "sk_test_*******",
       "publishable": "pk_test_*******"
     },
     "legal_entity": {
       "additional_owners": [
       ],
       "address": {
         "city": null,
         "country": "US",
         "line1": null,
         "line2": null,
         "postal_code": null,
         "state": null
       },
       "business_name": null,
       "business_tax_id_provided": false,
       "dob": {
         "day": null,
         "month": null,
         "year": null
       },
       "first_name": null,
       "last_name": null,
       "personal_address": {
         "city": null,
         "country": "US",
         "line1": null,
         "line2": null,
         "postal_code": null,
         "state": null
       },
       "personal_id_number_provided": false,
       "ssn_last_4_provided": false,
       "type": "individual",
       "verification": {
         "details": null,
         "details_code": null,
         "document": null,
         "status": "unverified"
       }
     },
     "metadata": {
     },
     "payout_schedule": {
       "delay_days": 2,
       "interval": "daily"
     },
     "payout_statement_descriptor": null,
     "payouts_enabled": false,
     "product_description": null,
     "statement_descriptor": "",
     "support_email": null,
     "support_phone": null,
     "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
     "tos_acceptance": {
       "date": 1509265479,
       "ip": "::1",
       "user_agent": null
     },
     "type": "custom",
     "verification": {
       "disabled_reason": null,
       "due_by": null,
       "fields_needed": [
         "external_account",
         "legal_entity.dob.day",
         "legal_entity.dob.month",
         "legal_entity.dob.year",
         "legal_entity.first_name",
         "legal_entity.last_name"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

   and some parts of the retrieved data are like below. Payouts is not enabled in the log but is enabled here. `fields_needed` is very different too.

   `{:details_submitted=>true, :charges_enabled=>true, :payouts_enabled=>true, :fields_needed=>[\"legal_entity.personal_id_number\"], :due_by=>nil}`

My Stripe controller is;

```
class StripeManaged < Struct.new(:org_person)
  ALLOWED = ['US', 'CA', 'TW'] # public beta
  COUNTRIES = [
    {name: 'United States', code: 'US'},
    {name: 'Canada', code: 'CA'},
    {name: 'Taiwan', code: 'TW'}
    # { name: 'Australia', code: 'AU' },
    # { name: 'United Kingdom', code: 'GB' },
    # { name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE' }
  ]

  def create_account!(country, tos_accepted, ip)
    return nil unless tos_accepted
    return nil unless country.in?(COUNTRIES.map {|c| c[:code]})

    begin
      @account = Stripe::Account.create(
        type: "custom",
        country: country,
        email: org_person.email,
        tos_acceptance: {
          ip: ip,
          date: Time.now.to_i
        },
        legal_entity: {
          type: 'individual'
        }
      )
    rescue
      nil # TODO: improve
    end

    if @account
      org_person.update_attributes(
        stripe_currency: @account.default_currency,
        stripe_account_type: 'custom', # name has been changed from 'managed' to 'custom'
        stripe_user_id: @account.id,
        stripe_secret_key: @account.keys.secret,
        stripe_publishable_key: @account.keys.publishable,
        stripe_account_status: account_status
      )
    end

    @account
  end

  def update_account!(params: nil)
    if params
      if params[:bank_account_token]
        account.external_account = params[:bank_account_token]
        account.save
      end

      if params[:legal_entity]
        # clean up dob fields
        params[:legal_entity][:dob] = {
          year: params[:legal_entity].delete('dob(1i)'),
          month: params[:legal_entity].delete('dob(2i)'),
          day: params[:legal_entity].delete('dob(3i)')
        }

        # update legal_entity hash from the params
        params[:legal_entity].entries.each do |key, value|
          if [ :address, :dob ].include? key.to_sym
            value.entries.each do |akey, avalue|
              next if avalue.blank?
              # Rails.logger.error "#{akey} - #{avalue.inspect}"
              account.legal_entity[key] ||= {}
              account.legal_entity[key][akey] = avalue
            end
          else
            next if value.blank?
            # Rails.logger.error "#{key} - #{value.inspect}"
            account.legal_entity[key] = value
          end
        end

        # copy 'address' as 'personal_address'
        pa = account.legal_entity['address'].dup.to_h
        account.legal_entity['personal_address'] = pa

        account.save
      end
    end

    org_person.update_attributes(stripe_account_status: account_status)
  end

  def legal_entity
    account.legal_entity
  end

  def needs?(field)
    org_person.stripe_account_status.match(Regexp.new(/#{field}/i)).present?
  end

  def supported_bank_account_countries
    country_codes = case account.country
                    when 'US' then %w{US}
                    when 'CA' then %w{US CA}
                    when 'IE', 'UK' then %w{IE UK US}
                    when 'AU' then %w{AU}
                    when 'TW' then %w{TW}
                    end
    COUNTRIES.select do |country|
      country[:code].in? country_codes
    end
  end

  protected

  def account_status
    {
      details_submitted: account.details_submitted,
      charges_enabled: account.charges_enabled,
      payouts_enabled: account.payouts_enabled,
      fields_needed: account.verification.fields_needed,
      due_by: account.verification.due_by
    }
  end

  def account
    @account ||= Stripe::Account.retrieve(org_person.stripe_user_id)
  end
end
```

I got these codes from a tutorial from 2015 and have been making changes according to what Stripe changed. Great if anyone can help me out with these problems. Thanks.

Comment: As far as #1, yes. You HAVE to contact customer support for that type of thing.

Comment: Please check this: https://gist.github.com/JagdeepSingh/166fa03829275cb6131d77abc6d4c148

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Spartacus and Jagdeep. Sorry for a long hiatus because I was super busy in Nov... Well, I thought of contacting the customer support but as long as my codes are the same, it happens again. So I think I need to come up with a way to send "personal id number" to Stripe when or before the account is "verified". But I'm not sure when the account is "verified" at this moment....